# How to access field values of an object from a ModelMultipleChoiceField, from within a template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I have a database of television channels that I am displaying using a Django form with a ModelMultipleChoiceField and a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.

The template renders fine, but how do I access fields of the individual objects that are part of the ModelMultipleChoiceField field of the form?

Channel model

```py
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the form

```py
class ChannelForm(forms.Form):
    channels_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Channel.objects.all().order_by('name'),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

This is how I was trying to access the 'name' field of each channel in the template by doing `{{channel.name}}`.

```html
{% for channel in form.channels_list %}
   {{ channel }}  accessing:  {{ channel.name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

When it renders it simply says "accessing: "  without the channel name

Here is my view.py as requested:

```py
def generage_recommendation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # POST code ...
    else:
        form = RecommendationRequestForm()
    return render(request, 'recommendation_home.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1):

in your **views.py**,
use `ChannelForm` instead of `RecommendationRequestForm`.

in your template, you can access field values of ModelMultipleChoiceField like this:

```
{% for key, value in form.channels_list.field.choices %}
  Channel ID = {{ key }}
  Channel Name = {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

(notice `.field.` code)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your **views.py** file.

You don't have to use 
`form.channels` in the template.

Try using this instead.

```
{% for channel in channels_list %}
   {{ channel }}  accessing:  {{ channel.name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just updated to included my views.py file.  I tried your suggestion and it did not work.  Nothing displayed